# SQL months_between grouping issue

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions, netezza

First post; go easy on me.

Relatively new to SQL (anything beyond simple queries really), but attempting to learn more complex functions in an effort to take advantage of superior server resources.  My issue:

I would like to use a SUM function to aggregate cash flows across a very large variety of sources.  I would like to see these cash flows along a monthly time period.  Because the cash flows start at different times, I would like to season them so that they are all aligned.  My current code:

```
select 
    months_between(A.reporting_date, B.start_date) as season,
    sum(case when A.current_balance is null then B.original_balance 
        else A.current_balance end) as cashflow

  from dataset1 A, dataset2 B

  group by season
  order by season
```

Now, executing the code like this generates an error message that states that A.reporting_date and B.start_date must be GROUPED or part of an AGGREGATE function.

The problem is, if I add them to the GROUP BY statement, while it generates output without error, I get cash flow sums that are essentially Cartesian crosses with all the grouped variables.

So long story short, is there any way for me to get cash flow sums grouped by only the season?  If so, any ideas how to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: did you add `group by months_between(A.reporting_date, B.start_date)` or the the seperate fields?

Comment: You have no join conditions between your two tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most databases don't allow using column aliases defined previously, in `where`, `group by` and `order by` clauses.

For your query you should use `months_between(A.reporting_date, B.start_date)` instead of the alias `season` in `group by` and `order by`.

Also your query will return a `cross product`, as a `join` condition isn't specified.

```
select 
months_between(A.reporting_date, B.start_date) as season,
sum(case when A.current_balance is null then B.original_balance 
    else A.current_balance end) as cashflow
from dataset1 A
JOIN dataset2 B ON --add a join condition
group by months_between(A.reporting_date, B.start_date)
order by months_between(A.reporting_date, B.start_date)
```

Comment: Postgres allows column aliases in the `group by` clause, so I assume that Netezza does as well.

Comment: vkp - Thank you.  There is actually a bit more code to all of this (including specified joins), but I stripped it out of the question for simplicity's sake.  Your suggestion works just fine, and I really appreciate it.  By grouping and ordering it by the months_between function, I get the cash flows exactly as I'd like.  Is there any way that you can think of to create that seasoning variable though?  Ultimately, I anticipate joining the various tables I create this way on said season.

Comment: you can look into `common table expression` so you calculate the season value once and use it later in your queries.